# WPF MVVM - how to clear a list when bound to an AsyncCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a ListView that is bound in the XAML to an AsyncCommand defined in the ViewModel.  All examples are cut down for brevity.

**XAML**

```
<listView ItemSource="{Binding Path=ReportCommand.Execute.Result}" />
<Button Command="{Binding ReportCommand}">Click</Button>
```

**MVVM**
In the constructor:

```
ReportCommand = new AsyncCommand<List<MyPoco>>(() => LoadReport());
```

In the class:

```
public IAsyncCommand ReportCommand { get; private set; }

private async Task<List<MyPoco>> LoadReport()
{
    return await _service.GetListOfPocos();
}
```

(fyi - this is based on Stephen Cleary's MSDN article)

okay, so far, all well and good.

However, on another control on the Window, the user does something that requires this ListView to be cleared (for example, they log out).  I know how I can get my various ViewModels to talk to each other behind the scenes, but how do I get to clear this "command" so that the List that is bound to by ListView is empty?

Thanks

Griff

Answer (score 1):

Could you not store the result of the async command in another property in your viewmodel, and bind your ListView to that property? That would give you complete control over how and when the content changes. Something like this:

```
public ViewModelConstructor()
{
    ReportCommand = new AsyncCommand(() => LoadReport());
}

public IAsyncCommand ReportCommand { get; private set; }

private async Task LoadReport()
{
    MyPocoList = await _service.GetListOfPocos();
}

public List<MyPoco> MyPocoList
{
    get { ... }
    set { ...; RaisePropertyChanged("MyPocoList"); }
}
```

and your XAML would change to:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyPocoList}" />
<Button Command="{Binding ReportCommand}">Click</Button>
```

If you needed to clear the listbox, you can simply set `MyPocoList = null;`

I'm assuming you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel with this example.

Comment: That's probably the way I'll go - I have various other UI controls linked to the ReportCommand (e.g.ReportCommand.Execution.IsNotCompleted and ReportCommand.Execution.ErrorMessage) but I guess there's no reason to bind to it's .Result.

Comment: Hi @DrGriff - did you end up going down this route, or did you find a different solution? Just noticed you'd not accepted the answer ;)